# Removing element from .NET array .remove method not working as expected (Powershell)

Tags: arrays, powershell, element

I have some code where I'm trying to use the .NET way of working with arrays in Powershell and the .remove method is not removing the element I want (processname "wssm" in examples 2 and 3). I'm doing something wrong and I'm not sure what it is.

1. The test example works when I populate specific elements using .add:

   -----------EX1-----------

   ```
   $foo = New-object System.Collections.Arraylist

   $foo.add("red")

   $foo.add("blue")

   $foo.remove("red")
   ```

   `$foo` returns a single element value "blue" (this is good).
2. When I try to populate the array with the results of Get-process (using two different methods below) and try to remove the element value "wssm" it does not seem to be able to find and remove it.

   ------------EX2--------------

   ```
   $test = New-object System.Collections.Arraylist(,(get-process |select processname))

   $test.Remove("wssm")
   ```

   -------------EX3------------

   ```
   $test = New-object System.Collections.Arraylist

   $test2= get-process |select processname 

   $test.Addrange($Test2)

   $test.Remove("wssm")
   ```

Examples 2 and 3 do not remove the element containing "wssm" and just returns the whole array list of processnames(wssm is shown as being present in the array) and throws no errors.

When I do a

```
$foo |get-member
```

It comes back with:

```
TypeName: System.String
```

And .remove IS listed as a method. When I do a:

```
$test |get-member
```

It comes back with:

```
TypeName: Selected.System.Diagnostics.Process
```

And .remove is NOT listed as a method (why this not not throw an error is unknown).

The results of `$foo` do not contain a header and the results of $test contain a header of "processname" from the select in my get-process step.

Is this a multidimensional array issue and I am just not using the correct syntax in my .remove("wssm") step? Or should I be declaring the array differently?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The array isn't passed to Get-Member, each element of the array is passed to it.  This means that the Remove that you found is String.Remove, not ArrayList.Remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fill the `ArrayList` with the output of `Get-Process` you're creating an array of objects. Calling the `Remove()` method with a string "wssm" won't do anything, because the array doesn't contain such a string object. Instead you need to identify the object with that process name and remove that object from the array:

```
$wssm = $test | ? { $_.ProcessName -eq "wssm" }
$test.Remove($wssm)
```

Comment: That will work, but might as well just do `$test = $test | ? { $_.ProcessName -ne "wssm" }`

Comment: That would also be an option, yes.

Comment: Those are great! Many thanks. So I don't even have to use the .NET form of the array. I had heard it was not easy to remove elements in native powershell but re-copying minus the ones you don't want works fine it seems.

Answer (score 2):

I saw somebody wrote this code but deleted afterwards:

```
$test = New-object System.Collections.Arraylist(,(get-process |select -expandProperty processname))
```

This is good too not sure why it gets deleted.

It seem if we don't expand property the new object "type" will be decided by "get-process" which is " System.Diagnostics.Process".

```
$test = New-object System.Collections.Arraylist(,(get-process |select  processname))
```

When we use the "-expandProperty" it becomes system.string:

```
$test = New-object System.Collections.Arraylist(,(get-process |select -expandProperty processname))
```

Actually this is a very good example showing up how expandProperty works.

Comment: Perhaps the user deleted the question because of my comment that expanding the property will put strings instead of process objects into the array. Which may be undesired, depending on what the OP wants to do with that array.